# Create prisma utility function with typescript

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have the following utility function but i don't know how to infer the type correctly:

```js
function utilityFunction<
  P, R, A extends unknown[]
>(
  prismaArgs /* "where" field now must be optional, because i already defined inside findUnique method below */,
  fn: (
    prismaData /* I want the same type of prismaData defined below (inside async function), but it must be determined dynamically, based on prismaArgs */,
    ...args: A
  ) => Promise<R>
){
  return async function(...args: A){
    const prismaData = await prisma.session.findUnique({
      ...prismaArgs,
      where: {
        ...prismaArgs.where,
        sessionId: getSessionId()
      }
    })
    return await fn(prismaData, ...args)
  }
}

const fn = utilityFunction(
  { 
    include: {
      user: { userId: true }
    }
  },
  async (prismaData, arg1, arg2) => {
    //    ^? (parameter) prismaData: { ...sessionField, user: { userId: string } }
  }
)

fn(arg1, arg2)
```

I actually managed to get the type inference on prismaData, but I used methods that don't follow best practices, such as casting and any, I wanted to find a more correct way

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved it this way:

```js
export function assertUser<
  R,
  S extends Omit<Prisma.SessionFindUniqueArgs, 'where'>,
  A extends unknown[],
>(
  prismaArgs: S,
  fn: (
    prismaData: Prisma.SessionGetPayload<typeof newPrismaArgs>,
    ...args: A
  ) => Promise<R>
) {
  const newPrismaArgs = {
    ...prismaArgs,
    where: {
      ...prismaWhereSafeSession(),
    },
  };
  return async function (...args: A) {
    const prismaData = (await prisma.session.findUnique(
      newPrismaArgs
    )) as Prisma.SessionGetPayload<typeof newPrismaArgs> | null;

    if (!prismaData) {
      redirect('/login');
    }

    return await fn(prismaData, ...args);
  };
}
```